Karate Rightclick using Javascript
I've tried right-clicking on the element in UI using the below JS in Karate, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.
 script("locator element","_.dispatchEvent(new Event('contextmenu'))")

Can someone please take a look and see what I am missing here?
